# difftime in R with date/times spanning midnight

Tags: r, difftime

I have a dataset where I am using difftime to calculate the difference between two times in R.  For 4 of the records that start in one day and continue past midnight I am getting nonsense answers.

Dataset

```
time2<-dput(time2)
structure(list(StationID = c(201707123L, 201710032L, 201710148L, 
201710188L), TowStartTime = structure(c(-2209057289, -2209057558, 
-2209057779, -2209057812), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    TowEndTime = structure(c(-2209142790, -2209143047, -2209143555, 
    -2209143587), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    tow_time = c(-1425.01666666667, -1424.81666666667, -1429.6, 
    -1429.58333333333)), .Names = c("StationID", "TowStartTime", 
"TowEndTime", "tow_time"), row.names = c(572L, 783L, 1003L, 1079L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Code used to calculate tow_tim

```
time2$tow_time<-as.numeric(difftime(strptime(time2$TowEndTime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                    strptime(time2$TowStartTime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),units="mins")
```

I have the end time in front of the start time because I didnt want to have negative values.  I get the same answers for the time difference either way its just not a negative value. Is there a way to account for going over midnight with difftime or another function in R to do this?

Comment: So the end dates are *before* the start dates? How does that make sense in the first place?

Comment: Its times not dates and I didnt want to have a negative time so I switched the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an error, in that cases you have a `TowStartTime` after a `TowEndTime`, so `tow_time` will be negative.

Example:

```
StationID        TowStartTime          TowEndTime  tow_time
572  201707123 1899-12-31 05:58:31 1899-12-30 06:13:30 -1425.017
```

In hour you can see that EndTime is 23 hour before startTime:

```
-1425.017/60
[1] -23.75028
```

This output is not wrong, maybe original data are.
You have negative time stamp that are convertend in uncommon date:

```
as.POSIXct(-2209143587, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "1899-12-30 06:00:13 CET"
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you change the code to start time minus end time you still get the same value without a negative symbol in front of it 1429.  Both time columns have a weird date in front of them.  Those dates are not the dates.  I have another column with the correct dates - should I replace the incorrect dates and run the same code?

Comment: You have negative time stamp that are convertend in uncommon date:

as.POSIXct(-2209143587, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "1899-12-30 06:00:13 CET"

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to use the interval function from the lubridate package.

However, it is still strange your endtimes are after your starttimes.

```
 > interval(df1$TowStartTime, df1$TowEndTime) %/% minutes(1)
 [1] -1425 -1424 -1429 -1429
```